# Unable to refer to infragistics ultra web grid control populated after an Ajax call in Selenium

Tags: ajax, selenium, infragistics

We are entering values in ultra web grid control which is populated from an Ajax call but when the Ajax call is completed, we are getting error element not found.

The complete sequence is as under:

Elements on the page:
Save & Cancel icons, A textbox, drop down, item picker, a popup, a textarea, a blank Infragistics ultraweb grid.
When first time page is loaded, all control gets initialized except ultraweb grid.
Now User clicks on item picker and selects an item from the popup. This action initializes the ultra web grid there on the page for the item details and its quantity by an Ajax call.

Now we are not able to refer to the ultraweb grid there on the page. Note that we are able to refer to all other controls.

Command sequence:

- clickAndWait | id=lnkNew
- click        | id=C1_stdItemNumber_btnAuto
- click        | //table[@id='C1xstdItemNumberxgrd_main']//tbody/tr//td/nobr[contains(text(),'textItem')]
- clickAndWait | //button[@type='button']
- waitForVisible| id=C1xgridActivity_main
- fireEvent    | id=C1xgridActivity_main          | focus
- fireEvent    | css=#C1xgridActivity_rc_0_2 > nobr     | focus         "This is failing"
- clickAt      | css=#C1xgridActivity_rc_0_2 > nobr                     "This is failing"
- doubleClickAt| id=C1xgridActivity_rc_0_8                              "This is failing"
- type         | id=C1xgridActivity_tb            | 1                   "This is failing"

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the issue.

Thing is when you load a page, in a DOM all CSS objects gets initialized but later on when an Ajax call is processed and completed, the CSS objects cannot be reinitialized in the same page, only the object which Ajax call processes gets intialized/populated.

You can resolve this issue using XPATH. You can refer to all elements there on the page after an Ajax call is completed. In this case WaitForElement command will be passed but later on when you will try to access the values of the element, that will fail when you will use CSS to refer an element.

Answer (score 0):

If you use jQuery library you can wait for AJAX call completeness with `waitForCondition` command:

```
 waitForCondition | selenium.browserbot.getCurrentWindow().jQuery.active == 0; | 20000
```

Comment: jQuery is not used here but we are using the command:[link](waitForCondition) | javascript{(selenium.browserbot.getCurrentWindow().$.active ==0);} | 30000. but still is is passing the command and stops at fireEvent command as mentioned above.

Comment: @tritium, actually `active` is a jQuery variable, so it is just another form of writing the same command. Anyway, if you use ajax instead of `clickAndWait | //button[@type='button']` use `click | //button[@type='button']` and after `click` insert this `waitForCondition` command. Btw you can remove all `fireEvent` commands as they have no sense here. And have you simple check your element's locator, maybe it is wrong.

Comment: @tritium - also it can be useful to insert `waitForElementPresent| css=#C1xgridActivity_rc_0_2 > nobr` before you interact with this element

Comment: @Aleh-Thanks for the reply. I resolved the issue.Thing is when you load a page, in a DOM all CSS objects gets initialized but later on when an Ajax call is processed and completed, the CSS objects cannot be reinitialized in the same page, only the object which Ajax call processes gets intialized/populated. You can resolve this issue using XPATH. I figured this and using XPATH, I am able to refer to all elements there on the page after an Ajax call is completed. In this case WaitForElement command will be passed but later on when you will try to access the values of the element, that will fail.